# question about Shared Policy in MEF with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mef

this is the table from the official MEF document

```
                 Part.Any    Part.Shared     Part.NonShared

Import.Any     Shared       Shared          Non Shared

Import.Shared   Shared       Shared          No Match

Import.NonShared Non Shared   No Match      Non Shared
```

My question is that for the "No Match" case(Export is shared but import is non-shared or reversely), which policy that the MEF will choose? (single or multiple instance) or just follow the policy from the Export?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No Match" means that the part cannot satisfy the import requirements. MEF will refuse to make such a composition.